# Python process doesn't work although it is alive

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    print(p.is_alive())
    p.join()
```

Although it prints that the process is alive the f() functions never runs. This is a simple code example that I want to help me understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: When I test it, I get the expected output `True` and `hello`.

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.9.7 x64

Comment: How do you call your script?

Comment: python file.py? i just use pycharm run button

Comment: I don't get the `hello` it only prints `True`

Comment: @sarema I use IDLE

Comment: I got `True` and `hello`--I think this is a problem with the system one uses. What editor are you using?

Comment: @GeorgeP run it from the shell or by some other means. Maybe IDLE is doing something funny with process management.

Comment: Running it from the shell won't work with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` when I tried it

Comment: A wild guess: the IDLE shell only attaches to the main program, but not to the spawned process. It therefore does capture the output of the second process.

Comment: I ran it in PyCharm, too. What is your Python version and library versions?

Comment: You are right it works fine with VS Code. The problem has to do with IDLE